# Empty email received when i enable 'Allow creating multiple accounts with same email' in Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have enabled 'Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address' in Firebase Authentication

[image]

After this change i am receiving empty email in user.email is that intentional? How can i read user's email in this case?

Comment: you have enable prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address

Comment: show the code for `user.email`

Comment: I am using the code give in Firebase docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin And the code is working fine when i disable multiple accounts with same email option

Comment: @karthikdivi did you a solution of this?

Comment: @sumit mehra No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the user with the empty email you are creating is a non-email/password user. If so, when "multiple emails per account" is enabled, the top level email, `currentUser.email` for these users is null which is what is used in the email templates. These users have their email populated in the corresponding provider is `currentUser.providerData[0].email`. Only email/password users have the top level email populated. This is to prevent email clashes as Firebase enforces top level email uniqueness.